# Probability Sum Insurance

Tags: percentages

An insurance company runs three offices, A, B and C. The company’s employees are distributed as follows: 30% work in office A, 20% in office B and 50% in office C. In office A, 10% are managers, in office B, 20% are managers and in office C 5% are managers:
(i) What is the total proportion of managers in the company?

Can someone clarify if I got the answer right?

Calculations for part i:

Office A: (0.30) x (0.10) = 0.03

Office B: (0.20) x (0.20) = 0.04

Office C: (0.20) x (0.05) = 0.01

```
                    = 0.08
```

This is what my teacher had?
Is this right? Because Office C should be (0.50) x (0.05) = 0.025

Comment: teachertypo i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office A and B are fine. For Office C, it should be $0.5\cdot 0.05=0.025$. Thus, the proportion of managers is $0.03+0.04+0.025=0.095$.

Comment: Thanks thats what I was thinking